# Retrieving data from database then display on tooltip

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How am I going to display my data from the database into my tooltip? Im having a hard time figuring it out

```
<input type="image" id="tip" src="image/check.png" title="<?PHP echo"$_POST['customerNo']";?>" style="position:absolute; top:400px; left:775px;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rewrite like this

```
<input type="image" id="tip" src="image/check.png" title="<?php echo $_POST['customerNo']; ?>" style="position:absolute; top:400px; left:775px;">
```

There need to some clearance between the `echo` statement and your `$_POST` variable.

Comment: as of PHP 5.3, you can do <?= $_POST['customerNo']; ?>

Comment: it wont work it said Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\tola\map.php on line 249

Comment: Avoiding short tags is the ideal way.

Comment: @user3396187, You won't get the error if you had used the way like I had shown. See this https://eval.in/116135